# How to open notification in app not in browser

Tags: android, webview

I'm making the app notification by using the OneSignal website and when I click on the notification that opens in the web browser, not in the app. But I want to open all notification on the app.

**Note: My App is working on webview.**

*Please help me with the notifications for the App.*

My Main Activity code:

```
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.Window;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        MyApplication myApplication;

        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myApplication = MyApplication.getInstance();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        }

    }


My Application Code:

import android.app.Application;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    public MyApplication() {
        mInstance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();

    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Post your code for notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add a deep link in my app and it's work.
Deep links work for notification and also all types of links.
It's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I tired with this one signal library version and it worked fine

Place this in build.gradle(app) file

```
//One Signal
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
```

Now create a Application class like this

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {

private static SampleApplication sInstance;
private static Context context;

public static SampleApplication getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
    context = getApplicationContext();
    MultiDex.install(context);

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotificationOpenedHandler(this))
            .init();
}

public static SampleApplication getAppContext() {
    return (SampleApplication) context;
}}
```

Now this **SampleApplication** in manifest file

```
<application
    android:name=".SampleApplication"
    ...
    ...
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
        android:value="DISABLE" />
  </application>
```

Here is my notification handler class

```
public class MyNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler, AppConstants {

private Application application;

public MyNotificationOpenedHandler(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Override
public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    String launchUrl = result.notification.payload.launchURL;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(launchUrl)) {
        startAppWithLaunchScreen();
    } else {
        startAppWithHomeScreen(launchUrl);
    }
}

private void startAppWithLaunchScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(application, SplashScreenActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    application.startActivity(intent);
}


private void startAppWithHomeScreen(String launchURL) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(application, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_SIGNAL_LAUNCH_URL, launchURL);
    application.startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Comment: what are you getting in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you wanted to handle the one signal notification in app directly.

Here is the code which i used long time back to perform the same:

```
try {
      OneSignal.startInit(this)
          .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
          .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotificationOpenedHandler()) //Handle notification Opened
          .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new MyNotificationReceivedHandler())
          .init();
      NotificationUtils
          .sendTag(MyNotificationOpenedHandler.APP_VERSION, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
      OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
        @Override
        public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
          notificationId = userId;
          Log.v("notificationId", "notificationId is " + notificationId);
          OneSignal.setSubscription(pref.getDataBoolean(PREF_IS_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED, true));
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
```

MyNotificationOpenedHandler that `implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler` which override the below method `public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {}` method will be called when user clicks on the notification where you can write your logic.

Here is the sample logic:

```
@Override

  public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    try {

      //To launch homepage if in case of no launchUrl. - IOS Limitation - cannot support http from panel.
      if (result.notification.payload.launchURL == null) {
        result.notification.payload.launchURL = "";
      }

      if (result.notification.payload.launchURL != null) {
        if (result.notification.payload.launchURL.startsWith("market://")) {
          String marketUrl = result.notification.payload.launchURL;
          AndroidUtils.openMarketLinkPage(context, marketUrl);
        } else {

          //Failsafe. Supports both http:// and without it.
          result.notification.payload.launchURL =
              "http://" + DeepLinkUtils.stripUrlSchema(result.notification.payload.launchURL);

          if (result.notification.isAppInFocus) {
            Intent mainIntent = NavigationUtilsKt.getHomeIntent(AppController.getInstance());
            mainIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRA_DEEPLINK_DATA, DeepLinkUtils
                .packDeepLinkData(NotificationUtils.NOTIFICATION,
                    Uri.parse(result.notification.payload.launchURL),
                    result.notification.androidNotificationId));
            mainIntent
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            AppController.getInstance().startActivity(mainIntent);
          } else {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),
                SplashActivity.class);
            mainIntent
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            mainIntent.putExtras(NotificationUtils.prepareNotificationBundle(result.notification.androidNotificationId));
            mainIntent.setData(Uri.parse(result.notification.payload.launchURL));
            AppController.getInstance().startActivity(mainIntent);

          }
        }
      }
      if (result.notification.payload.additionalData != null) {
        JSONObject campaignData = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        if (campaignData.has(CAMPAIGN_URI)) {
          GtmUtils.gtmPushNotificationClick(GTM_SCREEN_NAME_NOTIFICATION,
              campaignData.getString(CAMPAIGN_URI),
              campaignData.has(CAMPAIGN_EVENTS) ? campaignData.getString(CAMPAIGN_EVENTS) : null);
        }
      }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Hope this helps, Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Could you please help me with how to put these codes and where..?

Comment: The first one is under your Application class ( the class that extends Application which you could have mentioned in manifest xml as android.name).

And the second one is a new class MyNotificationHandler that implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler

Comment: I'm not understanding about MyNotificationReceivedHandler()..?